How does Oracle EM retrieve and display execution plan data?
I'm trying to query the execution plan information that I see in Oracle Enterprise Manager (EM) using SQL. I have been pulling data from the V$SQL_PLAN view, but I'm unsure which child cursor to select when there are multiple CHILD_ADDRESS entries. Should I be selecting the one with the latest TIMESTAMP?
Additionally, I'm struggling to replicate the sort order that EM uses. I've tried using ORDER BY ID, DEPTH, PARENT_ID, but the ID order doesn’t seem to match what I see in EM.
Here's the query I'm currently using:
SELECT * 
FROM V$SQL_PLAN 
WHERE SQL_ID = 'cgaryqcan3bh4' 
AND PLAN_HASH_VALUE = '1099020371'  
ORDER BY ID, DEPTH, PARENT_ID;


Can someone explain how Oracle EM retrieves and orders the plan data?

The package DBMS_SQL_MONITOR produces SQL Monitor Active Reports that are almost identical to the execution plans displayed in Oracle Enterprise Manager. For example, if you take the output from the below SQL statement, save it as a .html page, and open it in a browser, it looks almost the same as the page on Oracle EM.
select dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '26y1h6uxnzqdf', type => 'active')
from dual;

Although it's usually more convenient to generate the text version of the SQL Monitor Report, like this:
select dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '26y1h6uxnzqdf', type => 'text')
from dual;

If you don't have relevant SQL monitoring data or detailed plan statistics, you can view just the execution plans with the below SQL statements. The first one will look for a specific child cursor, while the second one will return data for all child cursors.
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '26y1h6uxnzqdf', cursor_child_no => 0));
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '26y1h6uxnzqdf', cursor_child_no => null));

You almost certainly want to use those packages instead of trying to recreate the results yourself through direct queries. There are a lot of painful details and quirks with execution plans that may take you a long time to reproduce through manual queries.
